# State Variable of solidity Contract could not be updated through JavaScript

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, javascript

I have following contract and just want to update its state variable values i.e. totalSupply. But when I try to attempt this task through JavaScript code (given below) by calling its function i.e. setTotalSupply, tts values is not updated.
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

```
contract MyContract {

    uint256 totalSupply; 
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    address owner;

    constructor(address payable _wallet) public {
        totalSupply = 10;
        owner = _wallet;
    }

    function () external payable{
        buyToken();
    }

    function buyToken() public payable {
        require(totalSupply >= (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2);
        balances[msg.sender] += (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;
        // wallet.tranfer(msg.value);
        totalSupply -=(msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;

    }
    function getTotalSupply()public view returns  (uint256 ){
        return totalSupply;
    }
       function setTotalSupply(uint256 newSupply)public {
        require(msg.sender == owner && totalSupply<1);
        totalSupply = newSupply;

    }
    function getBalance() public view returns  (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

i just want to update its value i.e. total supply. following is my JavaScript code for above purpose

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/7fb0bdc97c.....");
 const web3 = new Web3(provider);

var contract1  = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress1)
const txData2 = contract1.methods.setTotalSupply(10).encodeABI(); 
setSupplyBalance(contractAddress1, txData2);

function setSupplyBalance(contractAddress, txData ){

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
      txObject = {
      nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('100', 'gwei')),
      to: contractAddress,
      value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
      data:txData
    }




  const tx = new Tx(txObject, {chain:'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'})
// sign the trx
tx.sign(privateKey1)

serializedTx = tx.serialize()

raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction (raw, (err, txHash)=> {
    console.log('err:', err)
    console.log('txHash', txHash)
  })

  })

}
```

**UPDATED:** 
First i consumed all totalSupply (i.e. tokens) .. then i check its totalSupply and i got expected zero token. But, when i call setTotalSupply(10) and then check its values.. it still shows zero ... here is my checking code ...

```
var ot;

async function init() {
  ot = await contract1.methods.getTotalSupply().call();
  ot = ot.toString(10);
  console.log("Total Suplly is : ", ot);
  if(ot<1)
    console.log("OK")
  else 
    console.log("Bug !")
}
init();
```

Comment: What is the printout of your Javascript test?

Comment: sorry i could not got your point.. i didn't make any test... so what you want to know .. please specify ...

Comment: Your script prints something, right? What is it?

Comment: when i write a code to check its values (after consuming all its supply)  then it shows 0 ... But when i call setTotalSupply and set value 10.  and then check again its value ... but still it zero ... 
var ot;

async function init() {
  ot = await contract1.methods.getTotalSupply().call();
  ot = ot.toString(10);
  console.log("Total Suplly is : ", ot);
  if(ot<1)
    console.log("OK")
  else 
    console.log("Bug !")
}
init();

Comment: please see update...

Comment: Are you kidding me? You wrote a script for calling `setTotalSupply`. This script should be printing something. What does it print?????

Comment: sorry, i could not explain well. the output of setTotalSupply give me only the hash of tx like ... 
err: false
txHash 0xd762014661d9722e7e24ade94f67dae.......
and above tx is also inserted in my contract and block as well. But totalSupply remained zero...

Comment: You need to set callbacks for `transactionHash`, `receipt`, `confirmation` and `error`. You should expect the callback for `confirmation` to be called 12 or 24 times (can't remember for sure). See [this coding example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#id64) (assuming that you're using web3 v1.x).

Comment: @AmirAli Do you have the full transaction hash? In your comment it was cut and it is not enough to inspect the result on Etherscan.

Answer (score 0):

by making payable to my state variable and payable setTotalSupply  will resolved this issue